# Perl and MYSQL. Can I replace now() with variables?

Tags: mysql, perl

When I use code below it will get the results start from today and past week from the database.

Codes:

```
my $sqlMySQL = "
  SELECT LOT,DPPROGRAM,PROCESS,FILEMODDATE,COUNT(*)
  FROM dc_fst_metadata
  WHERE COMMENT='$comment'
    AND ***FILEMODDATE between date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and now()***
  GROUP BY LOT,DPPROGRAM,PROCESS";
```

The question is now I try to replace now() (it is because I would like to choose from the other day and track back to 7 days results instead of start from today) with variable and its get nothing from the db. Any suggestion or solution to put in the variable?

Codes after put in variable :

```
$datetime="2014-01-26 00:00:00"
my $sqlMySQL = "
  SELECT LOT,DPPROGRAM,PROCESS,FILEMODDATE,COUNT(*)
  FROM dc_fst_metadata
  WHERE COMMENT='$comment'
    AND ***FILEMODDATE between date_sub('$datetime',INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and '$datetime'***
  GROUP BY LOT,DPPROGRAM,PROCESS";
```

Thank you very much.
P.s. I am new in perl and MYSQL.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @deathron5000 its get nothing from the db but i m sure there is data inside the db. Sorry to confuse you, the codes got no errors. I modify the thread now.

Comment: try to print the SQL query and run it through mysql client. Let us know, if any errors appear

Comment: @user4035 THUMBS UP for you (your answer reminds me that I can check the sql statement through the client) and thank you for those for view this threads. I found out there is no error on the codes and the replacement is exactly works just that my collegue modified the date without telling me. This thread will keeps remind me check on mysql client all the times once i got errors. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert your Datetitme-String to a "database-date". Instead of

```
date_sub('$datetime',INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```

use:

```
 date_sub(str_to_date('$datetime','%y-%m-%d %T'),INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```

An Please (!) don't use literals in SQLs. Try to use binding